# How to add two linear fits to plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add two linear fits to my plot (Yes in ggplo2). The first fit will use all my points, the second will exclude a point (let's say first point).

```
dosis <- c(0.24, 0.33, 0.26, 0.18, 0.11, 0.05)
corriente <-c(301.3, 275.4, 253.8, 235.5, 219.8, 205.8)
library(ggplot2)
datos <-cbind.data.frame(dosis, corriente)
ggplot(datos, aes(x=corriente, y=dosis)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

This will give me my plot with my first fit (using all my points).. Now How do I exclude a datum and create the second fit?
Do I need to add another geom_smooth command?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another `geom_smooth()`, and specify a subset of your dataframe to plot in the second `geom_smooth()` call. Here, I've excluded your highest value for the `corriente` variable.

```
ggplot(datos, aes(x=corriente, y=dosis)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, #add a second geom_smooth line 
               #use only a subset of your dataframe
              data = datos[-1,])
```

[image]

Comment: Comparisons like `==` or `!=` should not be applied to [floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/). To exclude a point from the dataset it would be better to use the index. For instance, to remove the first data point in this set one could use `data = datos[-1,]` instead of `data = datos[datos$corriente != 301.3,]`. Alternatively, more lengthy commands like `!isTRUE(all.equal())` would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @RHertel, I didn't know about the issue with floating point values. I've edited my answer per your suggestion so people who see this question in the future subset the data correctly.